# Groovy is not displaying output on command line

Tags: java, groovy

I unsuccessfully attempted to install Groovy 1.8.6 (zip distribution) on a Win XP (sp3) machine yesterday and today (the error messages stated it was unable to find the groovyStarter then I received a lengthy stack trace...). Needless to say, it was a frustrating experience. So, I decided to use the Windows installer for version 1.8.5. Groovysh functions as it should but if I write a small Groovy script and place it in a file:

`println "Hello Groovy Programmer!"`

...no output is displayed. Using groovy -e "println 'Hello!'" has the exact same behavior.

Any ideas of what might cause this?

Thanks.

~Caitlin

Comment: I've just installed it (1.8.6, binary release) in my WinXP SP3 machine without problems. Check your environment variables (JAVA_HOME, GROOVY_HOME). Which output you get when you run "groovy -v"?

Comment: Also, do you have a copy of the _'lengthy stacktrace'_ from groovy 1.8.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "installing" the binary ZIP distribution.  You don't really install anything in the usual sense of the term... you just unzip the ZIP file wherever you like.  On my Windows XP laptop, I unzipped its contents into `C:\groovy-1.8.6\`.

I have heard some people complain of problems when they unzip into a path that contains spaces (such as `C:\Documents and Settings\YourUsername\Desktop`)... so perhaps that could be your issue, if you unzipped to your Desktop or something.

Just unzip the ZIP file somewhere, and add it's `/bin` directory to your PATH.  On a Windows XP machine:

1. Right-click "My Computer"
2. Select "Properties"
3. Go to the "Advanced" tab
4. Click the "Environment Variables" button
5. Edit the `PATH` variable, and add `C:\groovy-1.8.6\bin` (or whatever)

The [Groovy installation instructions](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Installing+Groovy) also suggest that you add a `GROOVY_HOME` variable (pointing to `C:\groovy-1.8.6`), and a `JAVA_HOME` variable pointing to the root directory of your Java JDK (***not*** the JRE located inside of the JDK).  However, to be honest, I only remember to add these two environment variables half the time when putting Groovy on a a new machine, and it's never caused me problems.

With the ZIP file unzipped, and its `/bin` directory in your `PATH`, you just open a command-prompt and type:

```
groovy <script name>
```

... or, to run the GUI interface:

```
groovyConsole
```

If by chance you saw those "groovyStarter" errors because you tried to run `startGroovy`, then use one of the two commands above instead.  The "`startGroovy.bat`" command is an internal script intended for indirect use through the other scripts under `/bin`.  It will throw a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter` stacktrace if you call it directly... because it needs one of the other scripts to set some variable prior to calling it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I followed your directions, ran groovy -v and saw this: Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Files\Apache (C:\Files\Apache)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Files\Apache (C:\Files\Apache)

Comment: What directory did you unzip the ZIP file to?  What does your PATH variable look like (i.e. could there be an older version of Groovy coming before the current version)?